# IOS Swift TableView: Is there a way to move first cell one row down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a fullscreen tableView but also have some space at the top when the viewcontroller first appears for a searchbar which disappears when you scroll the tableView, right now I'm hacking it by making an invisible cell at top, however is there a way for it to do so that only when you first load the viewcontroller, the first cell is about one row lower but can still scroll up to reach the full height of the viewcontroller, so the top of viewcontroller when you scroll back to top?

This is what I have right now:

[image]

The issue I'm having right now is that the invisible cell creates a huge empty space when u scroll down, see below:

[image]

Comment: Why u r taking empty cell at top? Can you explain more clearly about your requirement.

Comment: Im making a fullscreen tableView but with a searchbar as well on the top, the searchBar disappears when I scroll down the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you don't want the search bar to stick at the top of your view, so it must be in one of the tableView Cells, if this is true if you want to have an empty space under the search bar you can have another custom cell which you can customize its height in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt)` function.